# Open source CMS or framework solution for multiple shops

Tags: magento, open-source, content-management-system, shopping-cart, php

I want to make an online store management system which can manage multiple stores. There are different users who can create and manage their own stores. I know there are many open source systems for individual stores like magento, open cart, uber cart and etc. but is there any open source CMS or framework that supports this functionality ?

Comment: is it such that it can have multiple users who can manage their own stores ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that CMS and eCommerce are quite different things. It sounds like what you are looking for, is a platform on which you can run your business, i.e. eCommerce platform, rather than a platform for publishing and managing content (CMS).

Comment: actually I am looking for a content hosted by different shop owners on 1 platform under their names. but they will have a single checkout and a single cart. So every shop owner can add/delete/update his own shop only.

Answer (score 0):

All in all you might use a module like [this one](http://www.aitoc.com/en/magentomods_advanced_permissions.html)

What you need is simply advanced restriction to websites-categories-products. ETC.